# Java: Check if command line arguments are null

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am looking to do some error checking for my command line arguments

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    if(args[0] == null)
    {
        System.out.println("Proper Usage is: java program filename");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

However, this returns an array out of bounds exception, which makes sense.  I am just looking for the proper usage.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

The arguments can never be `null`.  They just won't exist.

In other words, what you need to do is check the length of your arguments.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Check how many arguments were passed in
  if (args.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("Proper Usage is: java program filename");
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

@jjnguy's answer is correct in most circumstances.  You won't ever see a `null` String in the argument array (or a `null` array) if `main` is called by running the application is run from the command line in the normal way.

However, if some other part of the application calls a `main` method, it is conceivable that it might pass a `null` argument or `null` argument array.

However(2), this is clearly a highly unusual use-case, *and* it is an egregious violation of the implied contract for a `main` entry-point method.  Therefore, I don't think you should bother checking for `null` argument values in `main`.  In the unlikely event that they do occur, it is acceptable for the calling code to get a `NullPointerException`.  After all, it is a bug in the caller to violate the contract.

Answer (score 12):

To expand upon this point:

It is possible that the args variable itself will be null, but not via normal execution.  Normal execution will use `java.exe` as the entry point from the command line.  However, I have seen some programs that use compiled `C++` code with JNI to use the `jvm.dll`, bypassing the java.exe entirely.  In this case, it is possible to pass `NULL` to the main method, in which case args will be null.

I recommend always checking `if ((args == null) || (args.length == 0))`, or `if ((args != null) && (args.length > 0))` depending on your need.

Answer (score 1):

You should check for `(args == null || args.length == 0)`. Although the `null` check isn't really needed, it is a good practice.

Comment: Unnecessary checks are NOT good practice.  The `null` check is unnecessary, but you are correct that the `length` check is necessary,

Answer (score 0):

if i want to check if any speicfic position of command line arguement is passed or not then how to check?
like for example
in some scenarios 2 command line args will be passed and in some only one will be passed then how do it check wheather the specfic commnad line is passed or not?

```
public class check {

public static void main(String[] args) {
if(args[0].length()!=0)
{
System.out.println("entered first if");
}
if(args[0].length()!=0 && args[1].length()!=0)
{
System.out.println("entered second if");
}
}
}
```

So in the above code if args[1] is not passed then i get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

so how do i tackle this where i can check if second arguement is passed or not and if passed then enter it.
need assistance asap.

Comment: Please make this a question. Since it does not answer the question, it doesn't belong here. By asking a question instead, you have a much better chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score -10):

If you don't pass any argument then even in that case args gets initialized but without any item/element.
Try the following one, you will get the **same effect**:

```
 
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String [] dummy= new String [] {};
        if(dummy[0] == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Proper Usage is: java program filename");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is totally incorrect.  If an application is launched with no command line arguments, the `main` method will be called with an `args` array whose length is zero.

Comment: @Stephen An array without any element inside, has zero length. Then what's wrong about my answer?

Comment: @Puspendu - what is wrong is that `dummy[0]` throws an array index out of bounds exception!!  Ditto if you change the program (back) to testing `args[0]` and run it with no arguments.

Comment: @Stephen I have not given any solution rather I tried  to describe the issue. Read "If you don't pass any argument then even in that case args gets initialized but without any item/element. Try the following one, you will get the same effect:"

Comment: OK - I understand now.  It would have helped if you hadn't mistyped your first sentence.  As written it is unintelligible.  I note that you quietly corrected it in your last comment.  Sneaky.

Comment: Well, It's nothing "Sneaky", I have just corrected a TYPO "the" to "then"

Comment: ... without saying so, and at the same time implying that I hadn't read your answer properly.  That's the sneaky part!

Comment: Please check now, I have corrected it on the main post.I appreciate your criticism will help me to become a better writer in future!

Comment: "I have not given any solution rather I tried to describe the issue". Then don't post an answer. Post a comment.

Comment: The "corrected" version doesn't actually illustrate anything.  You are just trying to test a "dummy" variable, not the actual parameters.  And what is more, if you run this "corrected" code you will get an uncaught exception ... not your usage message.  The best thing you can do with this Answer is delete it.