# how to debug byte code injected into VM at class load time?

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, bytecode, code-injection

Context:
In my Java project, I am byte-code injecting a class (say Injected.java) and also byte-code injecting a reference to a method in Injected.java, such that this method sets the value of an instance member. This is one way to verify that I am byte-code injecting the right thing.

Issue:
At run-time, the value of the instance variable is not set as expected - meaning that my byte-code injection obviously did not work well.

Question:
1) How do I examine the contents of my (newly injected + modified) class loaded in the JVM at run-time? (javap helps do this for existing classes)
2) Can I debug via Eclipse, the byte-code injected code? Is there a plug-in

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [javaassist](http://www.javassist.org/)

Let's go step by step:

1. Obtain the content of the class file(say, **Point.class**), that you want to modify by bytecode injection

   `BufferedInputStream fin
   = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("Point.class"));
   ClassFile cf = new ClassFile(new DataInputStream(fin));`
2. ClassFile provides addField() and addMethod() for adding a field or a method (note that a constructor is regarded as a method at the bytecode level). It also provides addAttribute() for adding an attribute to the class file.

   Note that FieldInfo, MethodInfo, and AttributeInfo objects include a link to a ConstPool (constant pool table) object. The ConstPool object must be common to the ClassFile object and a FieldInfo (or MethodInfo etc.) object that is added to that ClassFile object. In other words, a FieldInfo (or MethodInfo etc.) object must not be shared among different ClassFile objects.

   To remove a field or a method from a ClassFile object, you must first obtain a java.util.List object containing all the fields of the class. getFields() and getMethods() return the lists. A field or a method can be removed by calling remove() on the List object. An attribute can be removed in a similar way. Call getAttributes() in FieldInfo or MethodInfo to obtain the list of attributes, and remove one from the list.
3. Now, check, if injection really worked:

   `MethodInfo minfo = cf.getMethod("move");    // we assume move is not overloaded.`

   `CodeAttribute ca = minfo.getCodeAttribute();`

   there is a number of methods in **MethodInfo / CodeAttribute** to check

If you like it, please let me know. That case I shall put a more detailed blog at http://puspendu.wordpress.com/

Ref: [here](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial3.html)

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's use case, or answer either of his questions.  He wants to examine the bytecodes that he injected at runtime, not bytecodes that were injected into classfiles before execution.  (And as he states, `javap` does that anyway.)

Comment: BTW - it is rude to downvote someone elses answer.  And doing this on the grounds of irrelevance when your answer is even less relevant is pretty lame, IMO.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have learn to down-vote from stack-overflow.  see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868878/java-check-if-command-line-arguments-are-null. BTW, if you want to get up-voted, edit the answer, I shall up-vote it :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply - this addresses a way to determine if method injection happens correctly. Is there  way to find out the code inserted inside a method?

Comment: also additional explanation via a more detailed code example on your blog is totally welcome.

Comment: @crazy Surely, I shall post and let you know.