# Args guaranteed to be non-null?

Tags: java, jvm

In the following program, if this is executed (e.g. via command line), is args JVM independently guaranteed to not be null?

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Comment: For individual values e.g. `args[0]`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868878/java-check-if-command-line-arguments-are-null

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short answer: yes, it may have length 0 but will not be null.

Comment: @casablanca, Is there anything for a more recent version of Java?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12 -- this doesn't seem to have changed in the Java 7 spec.

Answer (score 3):

I can find no statement in the [Loading, Linking, and Initializing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.2) section of the *The Java Virtual Machine Specification* that requires the arguments to be non null.

So it must be assumed that `null` is permitted, and, pedantically, your program should be prepared to handle `null` arguments. Even if in typical runtime environments, such as starting a Java program using the `java` program to start a JVM on Linux, it will never be the case that the arguments are `null`.

Comment: …and the best way to handle `null` arguments here, is by throwing a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Holger No, that would be the *worst* thing to do. Throwing an uncaught `NullPointerException` is the right thing to do for a problem that indicates a programming error (a bug). But for an environment problem, or incorrect usage, the correct thing to do is to log a suitabler mesage and have the program exit with a non zero exit status.

Answer (score 2):

Double-clickable Application Bundles on MacOS still have a non-null array passed to main, even though there is no command line per-se.

The JVM specification does not specify if the array parameter to the main method can be null. See
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.2

However, the convention is that it will be non-null and it is unlikely that a JVM vendor would break that convention at this point.