# Out of bounds error instead of custom message

Tags: java

I used an if statement to give the user a custom error message when `args.length == 0`. However, when no argument is passed, instead of printing my custom message I get an out of bound error.

```
String w1 = args[0];
int n1 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
  for(int x = 0; x < n1; x++) {
    System.out.println(w1);
  }

String w2 = args[2];
int n2 = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
  for(int b = 0; b < n2; b++){
    System.out.println(w2);
  }

String w3 = args[4];
int n3 = Integer.parseInt(args[5]);
  for(int c = 0; c < n3; c++) {
    System.out.println(w3);
  }

  if(args.length == 0){
    System.out.println("Error: No user input.");
    return;
  }

  }
```

Comment: where is the codes ?

Comment: tried to upload a code snippet but I don't have enough experience points

Comment: Image ?? No. Paste code here.

Comment: Just edit your question and include the code there. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
if(args.length == 0){
    System.out.println("Error: No user input.");
    return;
}
```

Should be at the beginning, because when there are no elements in `args[]` and you access them like this:

```
String w1 = args[0];
int n1 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
  for(int x = 0; x < n1; x++) {
    System.out.println(w1);
}
```

You get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExeption`. Simply put the check for `args.length() == 0` should be at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Revised after code was shown.

[Java: Check if command line arguments are null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868878/java-check-if-command-line-arguments-are-null)

I recommend always checking if ((args == null) || (args.length == 0)), or if ((args != null) && (args.length > 0)) depending on your need.

```js
if((args == null) || (args.length == 0))
{
  System.out.println("Error: No user input.");
  return;
}

if (args.length == 1) {
  String w1 = args[0];
  int n1 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
  for(int x = 0; x < n1; x++) {
    System.out.println(w1);
  }
}

if (args.length == 3) {
  String w2 = args[2];
  int n2 = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
  for(int b = 0; b < n2; b++){
    System.out.println(w2);
  }
}

if (args.length == 5) {
  String w3 = args[4];
  int n3 = Integer.parseInt(args[5]);
  for(int c = 0; c < n3; c++) {
    System.out.println(w3);
  }
}
```

Comment: added the null check in, received the same error when no input was passed

Comment: Now that I see your code you are checking for empty args late.

Comment: Great then if you gave me a negative please change to positive. Glad to help. Next time give your source in your question.