# Why does the main() method doesn't throw formal and actual parameters mismatch error?

Tags: java

Why does a main() function in java doesn't throw a 'actual and formal parameters mismatch error' even if the program doesn't involve getting input from the command line.This is a sample program where the near() function has same number of actual and formal parameters and compiles without any error,whereas the far() method throws a parameter mismatch error since I haven't given any parameters while calling it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class Prime
{
 void near(int x,int y)
 { 
  System.out.println(x+y);
 }

 void far(int a,int b)
 {
  System.out.println(a+b);
 }

 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  Prime n=new Prime();
  n.near(5,4);
  n.far();
 }
}


C:\Users\hcl\Desktop>javac Prime.java

C:\Users\hcl\Desktop>javac Prime.java
Prime.java:20: error: method far in class Prime cannot be applied to given types
;
  n.far();
   ^
  required: int,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are confusing runtime and compile-time errors.

The error you have shown is not "thrown". It is a compilation error, indicating that you have a faulty method invocation in your code.

But there is usually no invocation of `main` in any Java code. `main` is the starting point for the program, and the invocation of it is done by the JVM itself at runtime. When you do not have a method invocation in your source, you will not get compile errors that relate to that invocation.

Second, when the JVM invokes that method, it will *always* pass a string array to it. If no arguments were present on the command line, the string array will be empty. You can write an example `main` that prints the length of the array and see for yourself.

Finally, if you don't have a `main` method that's specified exactly according to spec (`public static void` with a single parameter of type `String[]`), the JVM will issue an error when you try to invoke your program. So if you try to write your `main` with two parameters or with a parameter of type `int[]` or something like that, you will get an error. It won't be a compile error, as it is perfectly legal to have such a method in your program. But it will be a runtime error - as the JVM cannot find the entry point to your program.

Answer (score 1):

The `main` method is getting an empty `String[]` as input. Because that's the input: nothing.

Your function `far` needs input, so you have to give it input.

See [this post by jjnguy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3868882/2773311).

> The arguments can never be null. They just won't exist. -jjnguy

For example, if you run without command line arguments, you will reach this comment:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    if(args.length == 0){
        //there is no command line input, but args still exists
    }
}
```